# Making a button appear on scroll with Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The button already has Javascript this is why I'm including it below - this code is separate to my question though. This is to change the button into something else ON CLICK - I want to keep the button hidden, until scroll... Looked all over and I'm unable to find the right way. (very new to JS).. and whenever I fiddle with the code it's breaking the JS which is why I'm seeking help.. it would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mydiv").hide();
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("#mydiv").toggle();
    $("#show").toggle();
  });
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#mydiv").hide();
    $("#show").show();
  });
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 360px;
}

.btn-purple {
  width: 360px;
  background: #721a71;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.myheader {
  background: #721a71;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mybody {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn btn-purple" id="show">
  Get in touch <i class="fa fa-angle-up pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff; font-weight:bolder; font-size:20px;"></i>
</div>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="myheader text-center">
    Get in touch <i id="hide" class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff; font-weight:bolder; font-size:20px;"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="mybody">
    <p class="d-none d-md-block">Number: <a class="external" href="#">01522 123456</a></p>
    <p class="d-none d-md-block">Email: <a class="external" href="#">example@example.co.uk</a></p>
    <p class="d-none d-md-block">Bookings: <a class="external" href="#">booking.example.co.uk</a></p>
    <p class="d-md-none"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#">Call <span class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
    <p class="d-md-none"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#">Email <span class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
    <p class="d-md-none"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#">Book <span class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please describe "show on scroll", any scroll? Something specific?

Comment: I'm sorry. On my nav, I've done something similar which goes like this: .scrollTop() >= 500 ), I'd say the number for this one would be 1000. Struggling to get what I'm thinking into words... Let me know if you need more info and i'll try another way of wording it

Comment: Use display none and display block with vanilla js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach a scroll function to the window if you want to show your div on scroll [Jquery Scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/).  Then the easiest way if you are not that familiar with javascript is to just add a class and control everything else with css.  So you can just do something like the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#show').addClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 100);
});
```

This will add the class of `scrolled` when the window reaches 100px.  If you want it to also remove the class when it goes back up instead of using `addCLass` you can just switch that to `toggleClass` and it will remove it as well.

So here it is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mydiv").hide();
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("#mydiv").toggle();
    $("#show").toggle();
  });
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#mydiv").hide();
    $("#show").show();
  });
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
 $('#show').addClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 100);
});
```

```css
body{
  height:300vh;
}
#mydiv {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 360px;
}

.btn-purple {
  width: 360px;
  background: #721a71;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
.btn-purple.scrolled{
  opacity:1;
}
.myheader {
  background: #721a71;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mybody {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn btn-purple" id="show">
  Get in touch <i class="fa fa-angle-up pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff; font-weight:bolder; font-size:20px;"></i>
</div>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="myheader text-center">
    Get in touch <i id="hide" class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff; font-weight:bolder; font-size:20px;"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="mybody">
    <p class="d-none d-md-block">Number: <a class="external" href="#">01522 123456</a></p>
    <p class="d-none d-md-block">Email: <a class="external" href="#">example@example.co.uk</a></p>
    <p class="d-none d-md-block">Bookings: <a class="external" href="#">booking.example.co.uk</a></p>
    <p class="d-md-none"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#">Call <span class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
    <p class="d-md-none"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#">Email <span class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
    <p class="d-md-none"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#">Book <span class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you dont want the transition effect you can instead just use the display property and remove opacity and transition from the css like so:

```
.btn-purple {
  width: 360px;
  background: #721a71;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display:none;
}
.btn-purple.scrolled{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Works great :)   I've tried to replace "addCLass you can just switch that to toggleCLass" and it breaks the functionality. Not sure what I'm doing wrong there, but other than that, spot on :)

Comment: You may have spelled it wrong here it is working on a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/3e16qj76/ you can see that when you scroll back up the button disappears.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Steven :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 percent sure your requirement so I gave you something to start with.  I added an element to measure on window scroll that will scroll (first .big) that when off screen a bit will trigger one event and when back on screen shows via another event trigger.  I also put some style in the CSS that was in the markup.  Note you probably only need one of the hide/show and just need the up/down class thing instead but I left that alone for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show").on('click', function() {
    $("#mydiv").toggle(true);
    $("#show").toggle(false);
  });
  $("#hide").on('click', function() {
    $("#mydiv").toggle(false);
    $("#show").toggle(true);
  });
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var t = document.getElementsByClassName("big")[0];
    var tt = t.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (tt < -100) { // as soon as its 100px off screen
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#show").trigger('click');
      }, 1000);
    }
    if (tt >= 0) { // as soon as its back on screen
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#hide  ").trigger('click');
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 360px;
  display: none;
}

#show>i,
#hide>i {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.big {
  height: 20em;
}

.btn-purple {
  width: 360px;
  background: #721a71;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.myheader {
  background: #721a71;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mybody {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn btn-purple" id="show">
  Get in touch S<i class="fa fa-angle-up pull-right" aria-hidden="true">^^^</i>
</div>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="myheader text-center">
    Get in touch H<i id="hide" class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right" aria-hidden="true">xxx</i>
  </div>
  <div class="mybody">
    <p class="d-none d-md-block">Number: <a class="external" href="#">01522 123456</a></p>
    <p class="d-none d-md-block">Email: <a class="external" href="#">example@example.co.uk</a></p>
    <p class="d-none d-md-block">Bookings: <a class="external" href="#">booking.example.co.uk</a></p>
    <p class="d-md-none"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#">Call <span class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
    <p class="d-md-none"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#">Email <span class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
    <p class="d-md-none"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#">Book <span class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='big'>make me scroll</div>
<div class='big'>(I just take up space)</div>
```